# Discrete Structures : predicate logic (negation)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I got part 1 wrong but can't seem to figure out why.

All farmers -> not all farmers, grow corn -> grow only corn. When I put it together it made sense. Am i missing something?

Write the negation of each of the following

**1.    All farmers grow corn.**

Not all farmers grow only corn

**2.    Corn is grown only by farmers.**

Corn can be grown by non-farmers (is it wrong to use the hypothetical stance "can be" in predicate logic)

Answer (score 0):

I would read (2) as: for all corn, there exists a farmer that grows it.

So the negation says that there exists corn grown by someone other than a farmer.

This is a bit more precise than saying "can be." Just because corn can be grown by non-farmers doesn't mean it is actually grown by non-farmers. So your attempt at negating (2) does not actually contradict (2).

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense. It leaves room for abiguity. Thanks =D

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)